# How can one generate a view, with tallied sums from a secondary view?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a view, built to generate a validation report on a mission critical cron that runs weekly.  The view show weekly runs, 
Sum of total accounts credited, 
( some credit goes to SO buddies for my results!) , sum of OPEN accounts, sum of closed accounts, basic stuff.

```
mysql> select * from view_command_OPEN_CLOSED_tally limit 5;
+---------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+-------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| created             | total_accounts_credited | total_amount_credited | total_open_credited | total_amount_open | total_closed_credited| total_amount_closed|
+---------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+-------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| 2019-01-19 00:00:00 |                   18175 |               3173.68 |               16953 |           7063.68 |                 1222 |             110.00 |
| 2019-01-12 00:00:00 |                   18135 |               4768.43 |               17053 |           9358.43 |                 1082 |             410.00 |
| 2019-01-10 09:00:27 |                      80 |               1497.75 |                  80 |           1497.75 |                    0 |               0.00 |
| 2019-01-09 09:20:55 |                      51 |                933.50 |                  50 |            915.75 |                    1 |              17.75 |
| 2019-01-08 16:45:14 |                      10 |                187.50 |                  10 |            187.50 |                    0 |               0.00 |
+---------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+-------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
```

I assumed I could easily  generate a second view  from this one, with a subquery that would show difference in percentage from previous week.  IE:
Created, total_accounts_credited, difference_from_last_week_in_percent, total_ammount_credited,  difference_in_percent_from_last_week,  etc ...
I cannot get my previous week results to match the data and calculate percentage.  The resultset dispays some row of previous 
The queries I tried all revolved around a basic left join, but for some reason the "previous week" result is not shown at appropiate location.
I am obviously doing something direspectful to MySQL in my approach, and in response, it is spitting me out an incoherent resultset.

```
mysql> SELECT vtally.created,
    ->        vtally.total_accounts_credited,
    ->        vtally2.total_accounts_credited `previous`,
    ->        vtally.total_open_credited ,
    ->        vtally2.total_open_credited `previous`,
    ->        vtally.total_closed_credited,
    ->        vtally2.total_closed_credited`previous`
    -> FROM view_command_OPEN_CLOSED_tally vtally
    -> LEFT JOIN view_command_OPEN_CLOSED_tally vtally2
    ->   ON vtally.created = vtally2.created - INTERVAL 7 DAY
    -> GROUP BY
    ->   DATE(vtally.created)
    -> ORDER BY vtally.created DESC LIMIT 2;
+---------------------+-------------------------+----------+---------------------+----------+----------------------+----------+
| created             | total_accounts_credited | previous | total_open_credited | previous | total_closed_credited | previous |
+---------------------+-------------------------+----------+---------------------+----------+----------------------+----------+
| 2019-01-19 00:00:00 |                    8175 |     NULL |                6953 |     NULL |                  222 |     NULL |
| 2019-01-12 00:00:00 |                    8135 |     8175 |                7053 |     6953 |                  082 |     1222 |
+---------------------+-------------------------+----------+---------------------+----------+----------------------+----------+
```

The resultset above is an example, 
I would have expected result to be as follows, with every previous column holding previous's week result of column to its left:

(top row only, disregard bottom row)

```
+---------------------+-------------------------+----------+---------------------+----------+----------------------+----------+
| created             | total_accounts_credited | previous | total_open_credited | previous | total_closed_credited | previous |
+---------------------+-------------------------+----------+---------------------+----------+----------------------+----------+
| 2019-01-19 00:00:00 |                    8175 |     8135 |                6953 |     7053 |                  222 |     082 |
| 2019-01-12 00:00:00 |                    8135 |     8175 |                7053 |     6953 |                  082 |     1222 |
+---------------------+-------------------------+----------+---------------------+----------+----------------------+----------+
```

What am I missing to have proper "previous" total in proper column?

I believe it could be the Group BY, but have no idea where to go from here it seems tried all options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `vtally2` represents previous data, that means `vtally.created > vtally2.created`.

Therefore, change the minus into a plus: `vtally.created = vtally2.created + INTERVAL 7 DAY` in your join.

If you calculate, in a subquery, a column using a window function, you can also disregard your interval being **non-constant**.

Something like this:

```
WITH numbered_tally AS (
    select created, total_accounts_credited, total_open_credited, total_closed_credited,
           row_number() OVER (ORDER BY created) AS tally_number
    from view_command_OPEN_CLOSED_tally
)
SELECT  vtally.created,
        vtally.total_accounts_credited,
       vtally2.total_accounts_credited `previous`,
        vtally.total_open_credited ,
       vtally2.total_open_credited `previous`,
        vtally.total_closed_credited,
       vtally2.total_closed_credited `previous`
FROM numbered_tally  vtally
LEFT JOIN numbered_tally  vtally2
   ON vtally.tally_number = 1 + vtally2.tally_number
```

Comment: Ok. I knew it was a triviality, but did not expect THIS.  I wish I could send you a Canadian beer for this.  thanks bud!